# TypeScript Overload Signature Not Compatible With Rest And Array Overloads

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a method that accepts either an array of strings, or allow strings to be supplied as a rest parameter. When I try this, I get a compiler warning that "Overload Signature Is Not Compatible".

As the rest parameter results in a string array, shouldn't this be okay?

```
class Example {
    test(...strArray: string[]);
    test(strArray: string[]);
    test(strArray: string[]) {
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rest arguments get packed into an array at the function body, not at the call sites. The `(...strArray: string[])` overload only results in the first parameter being an array *when it is the implementation signature*, because the codegen for rest args is what packages the `arguments` into an array for you. The existence of other call signatures doesn't influence the codegen for the implementation signature.

In your example, if someone invoked `test('hi')`, `strArray` would be `'hi'`, not `['hi']`.

Comment: Excellent - and it has given me an idea for how to work around it! Thanks.

Comment: Here is my workaround: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201311/Blog/Allowing-Array-Or-Rest-Parameters-Using-Overloads-In-TypeScript/

Answer (score 1):

Potentially can be, but the compiler takes the literal meaning of `[string1,string2]` vs. `string1,string2` which are not compatible. So the only option

```
class Example {
    test(...strArray: string[]);
    test(strArray: string[]);
    test(strArray: any){
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
    }
}
```

You can always just use `['a','b']` to wrap the case for rest parameters:

Comment: Good answer - this would result in a length of `1` if rest parameters were used as the first argument would be assumed to be `strArray`.